# Jenkins Ivy Job Creating Multiple Workspaces

Tags: jenkins, ivy

I have an Ivy job that recently after I updated Jenkins and all my plugins started creating new workspaces each time the job builds.  Anyone know why?  The new build folders names match 'Execute concurrent builds if necessary', which isn't choosen.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your post while trying to find an answer to this problem for myself. This seems to be a bug in jenkins version 1.540. I rolled back to the LTS version [1.532.1], and its no longer creating multiple workspaces for ivy jobs.

Answer (score 0):

We had to use the ivy feature "Use custom workspace" and just put a path to where the normal workspace is.  I heard of people talking about the issue (would need to hunt to find it). Hopefully it get patched.

Comment: I did this as well.  This to me is a hack but is a valid solution if you can't downgrade as dropbear suggests.  I'm leaving dropbears answer as the correct one because it is better practice.

Comment: It seems the option doesn't always show for me in 1.551.1 and the issue is still present.  Any other workarounds/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to update Jenkins (and Ivy plugin) to the latest version (1.564).  I believe the cause was this issue:

[IVY plugin issue 14](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ivy-plugin/pull/14)

Which concerns not releasing workspace locks and most likely caused new work-spaces to be created.  Just update Jenkins, and from Jenkins update the Ivy plugin as the fix is already in plugin version 1.24.